# Unidac 5.0 performance degradation

Tags: delphi, postgresql-9.1, unidac

We migrated from UniDAC 4.1 to 5.0 (simply rebuilded or app with new version) and catch huge degradation in our datapump routines.

Running pgfouine catch many queries like:

```
SELECT current_database() AS DATATYPE_CATALOG, 
n.nspname AS DATATYPE_SCHEMA,
t.typname AS DATATYPE_NAME,
t.oid AS DATATYPE_OID,
t.typlen AS DATATYPE_LENGTH,
CASE WHEN t.typtype = 'b' THEN 'base' 
    WHEN t.typtype = 'c' THEN 'composite' 
    WHEN t.typtype = 'd' THEN 'domain' 
    WHEN t.typtype = 'e' THEN 'enum' 
    WHEN t.typtype = 'p' THEN 'pseudo' 
END::varchar(9) AS DATATYPE_TYPE,
t.typrelid AS TABLE_OID, 
t.typbasetype AS DATATYPE_BASETYPE 
FROM pg_type t 
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace 
WHERE t.oid = '' AND t.typtype = '' 
ORDER BY n.nspname, t.typname;
```

It executes more than 1,100,000 times for 210,000 data inserts.
Why it had happened and how avoid it on current version?

We does TUniQuery.Prepare once before insert loop and reassign query params inside.
On UniDAC 4.1 it works fine.

UPD.
Searching minimal reproduceable application/database i found out, that it occurs if 
we use domain datatypes in tables.

```
    CREATE DOMAIN id_dom AS integer NOT NULL;
    CREATE TABLE test_table (id id_dom);
```

Minimal application:

```
    program minProject;

    {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
    uses
    Messages, SysUtils, Variants,
    DB, DBAccess, Uni, UniProvider, PostgreSQLUniProvider;

    const text = 'insert into test_table (id) values (:id)';

    var
    qu:TUniQuery;
    PostgreSQL: TPostgreSQLUniProvider;
    UniConnection1: TUniConnection;
    i: Integer;
    ids: Variant;

    begin
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    UniConnection1 := TUniConnection.Create(nil);
    PostgreSQL := TPostgreSQLUniProvider.Create(UniConnection1);
    UniConnection1.ProviderName := 'PostgreSQL';
    UniConnection1.Username := '';
    UniConnection1.Password := '';
    UniConnection1.Server := '';
    UniConnection1.Database := 'test';
    UniConnection1.SpecificOptions.Values['ProtocolVersion'] := 'pv30';
    ids := VarArrayOf([41750, 41751, 41752]);
    qu := TUniQuery.Create(UniConnection1);
    qu.Connection := UniConnection1;
    qu.SQL.Text := text;
    qu.Prepare;
    for I := 0 to 2 do
    begin
        qu.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := ids[i];
        qu.Execute;
    end;
    qu.Close();
    end.
```

if used usual data types all is ok.

UPD2:

### [Answer from DevArt:](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?p=91773#p91773)

> Thank you for the information. We have reproduced the problem and are investigating it. We will inform you as soon as we have any results.

Comment: What did devart say when you spoke to them?

Comment: i didn't asked devart yet.

Comment: Well, that's your next move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version 5.0.1 there was added full support for domain types (that was absent in the version 4.1), due to this we had to request additional metadata from a database. 
We've released a new build of UniDAC - 5.0.2 - it contains a fix that improves performance when working with domain types. Now UniDAC works as fast as UniDAC 4.6.12, even if  a query contains fields with domain data types.